10th Anniversary of Community Building SE!
Earlier this month Community Building SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community (pun intended) for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!
